# Cors issue specifically in Internet Explorer XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Cors issue specifically in Internet Explorer only when
calling API from ajax call.

1)Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow- 
  Headers list
2)XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

I tried by followings

```
   xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
    }
```

also by setting 
...

crossDomain: true

...

headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },

Ajax call

```
    var url = "https://dev-connectivity.dummylink";
 var data = JSON.stringify({    
    "lang": "en",
    "ClientId": "asdfasf3452345c42352345c",
    "CountryCode": "34"
});  

     $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("tets");
    },
    error: function (error) {
       alert("error");
                }
});
```

//My api Webconfig code

```
     <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

// also Enabling Cors in startup

```
          services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

Comment: `headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },` is useless on the Ajax call.

Comment: a lot of browsers do not like `*` as values

Comment: I had also tried this var url = "https://dev-connectivity.dummylink";  headers: {
           
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': url
          
        },

Comment: Please try to go to Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites menu and add the domain to the trusted site list. other thing you can try is go to Security Tab (Internet Options> Security tab> Custom settings) make ENABLE The Following setting: Miscellaneous> Access data sources across domains. You can try to test this on your side and let us know about your testing results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't accept Content-Type header if you have provided * in you web.config file so to fix this issue, you need to manually add Content-Type header in Access-Control-Allow-Headers list inside your web.config file.

```
  <customHeaders>
     <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Any-Other-Header" />
  </customHeaders>
```